# VB.NET Using a dataset to spawn datatables for different forms

Tags: xml, vb.net, forms, datatable, dataset

Okay this is my challenge that I can't figure out. I have multiple forms(dialog windows) that get user entered information. I started a class that houses a `public property dsData as DataSet = New DataSet("ProjectData")` In each form I create an instance of the Project class `Dim cData As New Project`and create a datatable from the dsData dataset. I'm able to enter data into those dialog forms close them and reopen them and life is good the data remains until the application is close as it should.

My problem though is when I export dsData to xml `cData.dsData.WriteXml(xmlSW, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)` It's only exporting the setting in the datatable on the form that has the save button.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the .Clone method

```
public property dsData as DataSet = New DataSet("ProjectData")

Dim ds2 = dsData.Clone()
cData.dsData.WriteXml(xmlSW, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
cData.ds2.WriteXml(xmlSW, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
```

Comment: Is this from within the Project class? Currently I have the save code inside a toolstripmenuitem. Thinking about it now though it does make a lot of sense to include the saving of the dataset to xml into the Project class that has the public property dataset. I ask because ds2 is not a property or member of the Project class.